# System indentification different inputs

Tags: linear-systems, control-systems, system-identification

I have peformed different form for input/output relation to determine a system, but seem to be missing some theory which input will be the most will excite enough modes such that the models which i end up with will be accurate..

I tried Impulse response, step response and sine sweep.

Could somebody provide me with some litterature which explains discusses these method, and which one will create an accurate result. 
I feel like the sinesweep is more accurate, most because it has excited all the modes/configuration of the system, and the impulse and step haven't seem to be doing so.. but still litterature would be appriaciated.

Comment: Umm.  Robot?  What's a robot got to do with determining the response of a system?

Comment: Typo... (copy paste typo from a ebay search) :P

Comment: It really depends what you're trying to find, and what disturbances are acceptable to the system you're perturbing. In my line of work (heavy industry) sine sweep is out of the question because no plant manager is going to let you oscillate their plant. Steps are acceptable to them, and provide a fairly rich set of input frequencies. On the other hand, if you're bench-testing electronics and you're allowed to fry the test unit, sweep away.